# Windows Server DNS forwarding inside zone

Tags: dns-zone, windows-server-2019

I am using a Windows Server 2019 configured as domain controller with DNS (only secure updates). DNS forwarding to my router is also configured.
The mail server is not within Active Directory and therefore uses the DNS service of the router.

Both servers end with "<>.testdomain.local". How can I get the Windows DNS service to resolve the mail server through the router?

All other addresses (on the Internet) are resolved correctly.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both servers end with "<>.testdomain.local". How can I get the Windows
>   DNS service to resolve it through the router?

You can't. Your DC is authoritative for that zone. It isn't going to forward a request for a DNS RR that should be in that zone to another DNS server.

What you can do is to add a static A record in the zone on the DC for the mail server.